# How do I find call out bubbles in an image?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image-processing

Hi I have an image that has call out bubbles in it (call out = comic book text bubbles - i didn't know they were called that). I need to find where each of these are in a given image and get the location and size of each of these. Thanks!!\

AS3, Flex, Bitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a tough one actually. You want to do shape recognition with variable shapes ?
You've probably seen the [FlashSURF](http://www.psyked.co.uk/adobe/flash/link-flashsurf-complex-image-recognition-in-flash-player.htm) lib... It's pretty complex already but it obviously recognises predefined markers. If you read through Eugene's blog you will probably find some interesting pieces for what you need (edge detection specially).

A quick fix could be to preprocess/simplify the image a bit in order to contrast the bubble more against the rest and after check for abnormally big areas with a certain colour (if you're lucky enough to have the same colour for all the bubbles). There's a pretty handy in-built method with the BitmapData object called getColorBoundsRect(), it won't find your bubbles out-of-the-box but with some tweaks it could do the trick (I've used it for similar ends)

Comment: Thanks Theo. I think that FlashSurf may do it but like you said it is a complex route I'm not sure I want to go down. I think I can get it working with the BitmapData methods.